# why is the if statement always true?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
#include <stdbool.h>
//functions
bool check_letter_validity(char);

int main() {
    int score=0;
    char c=0,x=0,previous_value=0;
    printf("Please Enter Cool Letter : \n");
    scanf(" %c", &c);
    printf("Please Enter Text : \n");
    while (scanf(" %c", &x) == 1 ){
        if (check_letter_validity(x)==false) {
            score = -1;
            break;
        }
    
        if (x == c || x == c-('a'-'A')){
            score++;
            if (previous_value == c || previous_value == c-('a'-'A'))
                score++;
        }
        previous_value = x;
    }
    printf("The score is: %d", score);
    return 0;
}

bool check_letter_validity(char x){
    if (x==' ')
        return true;
    if (x<='z' && x>='a')
        return true;
    if (x>='A' && x<='Z')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

This is a code I wrote in which I receive a "cool letter" such as b and then receive a text such as "bhkb kBfj" and I have to scan the text for the letter 'b/B' and each b that is scanned increases "score" by one point.

Anyway, the problem is I have an if statement that is always true. For some reason, the if statement is always true even though it is supposed to be true only when chars that aren't English letters or spaces appear. Why is it the if statement is always correct? The output I receive:
Please enter cool letter:
(input) b.
please enter text:
(input) bhk kBfj
the score is: -1.

The score in this example is supposed to be 2, but it seems at some point the if statement returned false even though i haven't entered any false letters (such as *,%).

Comment: You need to learn how to debug your code. Write tests for your functions and see if they work as expected. If yes - look for another problems. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/dbsEds5MT

Comment: You set score to -1 before exiting the loop, then the displayed result will always be -1.

Comment: This looks very similar to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77916160/why-is-my-code-always-entering-the-if-condition#comment137362700_77916160)

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.  In particular, you don't need three `if` statements (you haven't identified which one is surprising you).

Comment: Your `check_letter_validity()` is fragile, as it will give unexpected results in locales where the letters aren't consecutive (e.g. when using EBCDIC character coding).  Probably better to include `<ctype.h>` and write `return x==' ' || isalpha(x);`.

Comment: I cannot duplicate your result with this code after you added the space before `%c` that the previous question was missing. https://godbolt.org/z/h5q8jP1sh My score is 3 though and not 2. If you are supposed to get 2 then you have a mistake in your algorithm. Are you certain you have recompiled and are running this exact code? The code shown is missing `#include <stdio.h>` which I assume could be a copy/paste issue but you should check that.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem come from `scanf` which is not the best tool to read one character from `stdin`. A better approach could be to use `getchar()` function:

Instead of

```
char c;
while(1 == scanf("%c", &c)) {...}
```

type

```
int c
while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {...}
```

---

But if you only change that, you'll have a problem since `stdin` will return a `\n` char, so you'll have to deal with it. You can add the case in `check_letter_validity()` or use some `clean_stdin` function (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17319153/1212012).

So your code could be:

```c
void clean_stdin(void)
{
    int c;
    do {
        c = getchar();
    } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

int main() {
    int score=0;
    int c=0,x=0,previous_value=0;
    printf("Please Enter Cool Letter : \n");
    c = getchar();
    clean_stdin();
    
    printf("Please Enter Text : \n");
    while ((x = getchar()) != EOF ){
        if (check_letter_validity(x)==false) {
            score = -1;
            break;
        }
    
        if (x == c || x == c-('a'-'A')){
            score++;
            if (previous_value == c || previous_value == c-('a'-'A'))
                score++;
        }
        previous_value = x;
    }
    printf("The score is: %d", score);
    return 0;
}
```

---

To finish.

You expect your user will a upper case letter, but what if he doesn't ?

You could use `tolower` (or `toupper`) to check:

Store your cool letter as a lower case letter:

```
c = tolower(getchar());
```

and before your check code, just type:

```
x = tolower(x);
```